# how can I parallel this loop with innerloops using openMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am not good in parallel programming but I need to do this loop more faster. I know how to use the library but I am not sure about if the output is right because the output is very close to be zero, but is not.

```
for ( int l = 0; l < s; ++l ) {

    double denonimator_l = 0;

    for (int g = 0; g < G; ++g ) {
        double &pi_gl = pi(g, l) = w[g];

        for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i )
            pi_gl *= P[g](i, Y(l, i) - 1);

        denonimator_l += pi_gl;
    }

    for (int g = 0; g < G; ++g ) {
        double &pi_gl = pi(g, l);
        pi_gl /= denonimator_l;
    }
}
```

I need to parallel the four loops and not just the first.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
```

So, I am not sure if I put the line above in the first loop is enough. Also, I need the correct output and I don't know if I am doing something wrong if I don't use private variables because I am using read/write operations.

The loops are not prefect nested so I can't use collapse.

Note that each cycle has a temporary loop variable.

Comment: The meaning of your parentheses (`operator()` I imagine) not being given, it is hard to say for sure. Assuming that `pi_gl` is something like a reference to `pi[g][l]` or, better (for performance), to `pi[l][g]`, then just adding `#pragma omp parallel for` on top of your outermost loop should be enough for parallelising the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, the operator() is for a data type matrix, that is vector of vectors from std library so Y(l,i) is Y[l][i]  and pi_gl is similar. I need the max parallel for this loop.

Comment: Two points: 1/ as already said, a simple `#pragma omp parallel for` before your `l` loop should be enough for a full parallelisation of your code snippet; and 2/ you do realise that the order of your indexes is just not good for performance, right? Your loops trigger strided accesses to data (for all but `Y`, for which accesses are linear) leading to terrible performance. You really should fix this before to think parallelisation, as the performance penalty is likely way higher than whatever parallelism can gain you.